# Offset or weight in binomial GLM - account for distance to road on animal sightings

Tags: generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, weights, offset

I am building a species distribution model for an animal, using data collected by community members when they sight this animal. My first step is to fit a generalised linear model with family binomial against several environmental variables, and then use this model to predict occurrence to a broader area.

The raw data has only presences, but I have generated pseudo-absences. So occurrence data are 0 and 1s (absences and presences). Community sightings are biased towards developed areas and alongside roadsides therefore I want to account for this in my model, so that when I predict to the broader area I don't have elevated occurrences close to roads.

I have modelled the data this way:

```r
Rasters <- stack(EnvironVariable1 , 
             EnvironVariable2, EnvironVariable3)

Occurence <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
               1)
EnvironVariable1 <- c(0.6, 1, -0.2, 0, 0.1, 
                      -0.9, 1, 0.7, 0.8, -0.9, 
                      0.3, 0.3)
DistanceRoad <- c(10.0, 9.2, 0.5, 0.85, 0.98, 
                  1.3, 0.56, 6.7, 5.4, 0.7, 2.3, 
                  2.6)
Data <- data.frame(Occurence, EnvironVariable1, 
                    DistanceRoad)

model <- glm(Occurence ~ EnvironVariable1 + 
             EnvironVariable2 + 
             EnvironVariable3,
             offset = DistanceRoad, data = Data,
             family = binomial(link = "logit"))

p <- predict(Rasters , model)
```

However I'm unsure if this is doing what I want it to do (i.e. accounting for and reducing the predicted occurrence by distance to road). I am wondering if weights might be more appropriate - so that sightings closer to roads are given less weight than those further from roads.

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset?  What do you mean by "presence and absences"?  Is `Occurence` 0/1, or is it a count?  Do you have data on instances where there could have been a sighting but there wansn't one?  I think we need to know more about the structure of the data.

Comment: I have updated the original question explaining the structure of the data more. Thanks!

Comment: Neither offsets or weights are appropriate here. To adjust for distance from the road, or to adjust for any similar covariate, you simply include distance as another covariate in the linear model. An offset would only be appropriate if you already knew how occurrence depends on distance, which you don't. Weights are something else altogether, especially for binary regression where they are almost never appropriate.

Comment: Thank for the info Gordon! My worry is, if I put distance to road as a covariate in the model (and lets assume there is a relationship), when I go to predict values, will I not end up with higher occurrence predicted near roads (which probably isn't actual what is happening in reality).